# What is the difference between ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables and ProcessStartInfo.Environment

Tags: c#, .net-core, process, environment-variables

[`ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables):

> A string dictionary that provides environment variables that apply to this process and child processes.

[`ProcessStartInfo.Environment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environment):

> A generic dictionary containing the environment variables that apply to this process and its child processes.
>
> **On .NET Framework applications**, using the Environment property is **the same** as using the EnvironmentVariables property.

And on **not .NET Framework applications**, what is the difference between `ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables` and `ProcessStartInfo.Environment`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They have different return types, but otherwise there is no functional difference.

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13948), the *.NET Core* language designers wanted to use a standard `IDictionary<>` rather than the somewhat archaic `StringDictionary` used by the original `EnvironmentVariables` property. They couldn't change the return type of the existing property without breaking compatibility with *.NET framework*, so they added a new, mostly redundant, property.

Comment: In other words, the .NET Core team initially started trying to reinvent every wheel, but were later forced into supporting backwards compatibility.

Comment: That is not the only difference. I haven't done enough work investigating to write a proper answer, but I ran into the existence of the two when struggling with an ArgumentException when adding a variable to EnvironmentVariables (on Linux). Using Environment instead solved my problem. See this discussion for more: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/19142

Comment: I believe the case sensitivity issues discussed in that link no longer exist. Both `Environment` and `EnvironmentVariables` are case insensitive on Windows and I believe both are case sensitive on Linux.